# Stuck in automatic repair loop and registry hive drive is zero bytes

Tags: windows-10

I just set up a new computer (the HP Spectre) the other day, and last night I got stuck in the automatic fix loop. I followed the instructions on this site:
https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/139576-startup-repair-infinite-loop-recovery.html

But when I got to the directory where I can see the registry hive drive, all of the folders are zero bytes. Is there a way to fix this? Or do I have to do a factory reset and start over?

Here's what I see:

```
C: \Windows\System32\RegBack
0 DEFAULT
0 SAM
0 SECURITY 
0 SOFTWARE
0 SYSTEM
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this lesson to heart: When it comes to low-level OS problems the exact Windows version really matters. In case of Windows 10 even the build-number can be important.

Those instructions are for Windows 7 and don't work properly for Windows 10 (for Windows 8 maybe, I never tried).

As far as I know Windows 10 works slightly different, especially when it is applying "updates", which in some cases aren't updates at all, but complete OS upgrades.

It seems you made the matter worse.
Better to start all over. That is less work than trying to fix the issue.

Comment: I could't get to the point where I could do anything, that's my question. I don't know what to do because the files are empty.

Comment: @andrewbuikema You were not clear about that in the question, but anyway the way Win10 dies things is different. I don’t have a Win10 System at hand at the moment, but I seem to recall these are not folders or files but hardlinks in Win10, which may look as 0-byte files.